# Multiple gsub pattern in column data frame

Tags: r, gsub

This is `head` of my dataframe:

```
dput(head(cibersort2))
structure(list(B_cells_memory_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.013586370789951, 
0), Plasma_cells_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0.0301693273396502, 0.00708056535230457, 
0.00482186691641502, 0.00361867019091323, 0.00175056912202556
), T_cells_CD8_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.00366272764460954, 
0.0129339156481784), T_cells_CD4_naive_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), T_cells_CD4_memory_resting_CIBERSORT = c(0.41371431035232, 
0.33703829491927, 0.333867816389315, 0.314760177785407, 0.0468307272849729, 
0.0725118104429426), T_cells_CD4_memory_activated_CIBERSORT = c(0.00891143704240062, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), T_cells_follicular_helper_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0.0347293081330928, 
0, 0, 0, 0.0133747079106891), T_cells_regulatory_.Tregs._CIBERSORT = c(0, 
0.0129423103250959, 0, 0, 0.0234394096487879, 0.0069569320148469
), T_cells_gamma_delta_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0, 0.0123576887209117, 
0, 0, 0), NK_cells_resting_CIBERSORT = c(0.0943573472038016, 
0.0291772819027654, 0.0603000015208808, 0.088050134860913, 0.0311098935569788, 
0.0493612123560175), NK_cells_activated_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0), Monocytes_CIBERSORT = c(0.0016366969648675, 0.00631279615260553, 
0.0551932054151082, 0, 0, 0.0123943209735217), Macrophages_M0_CIBERSORT = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Macrophages_M1_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0.00627375639050013, 
0.00342223629317283, 0.0177917365889883, 0, 0), Macrophages_M2_CIBERSORT = c(0.00426967800946337, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Dendritic_cells_resting_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0.0179649939115712, 
0.0118731989794404, 0.00708670828242363, 0.0182321843082775, 
0.00982198585327898), Dendritic_cells_activated_CIBERSORT = c(0.0225861928752029, 
0.0109379985095887, 0.00297876484852198, 0, 0.00709198645869268, 
0.00859026632295834), Mast_cells_resting_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0, 
0, 0.0933748210696562, 0.794200521163851, 0.731454661004374), 
    Mast_cells_activated_CIBERSORT = c(0.0660395349242789, 0.0595013316008351, 
    0.192793829859199, 0.0258173259198326, 0.026705625128166, 
    0.0430586213271918), Neutrophils_CIBERSORT = c(0, 0, 0, 0.053334303462807, 
    0, 0), T_cells_MCPcounter = c(0.397022910411154, 0.932823572403055, 
    0.418549146259903, 1.10730216871399, 0.0711693351364203, 
    0.337332284321366), CD8_T_cells_MCPcounter = c(0, 0.0552693563802698, 
    0, 0.112394311231942, 0.0977117739918182, 0), Cytotoxic_lymphocytes_MCPcounter = c(0.00288836029395812, 
    0.0946867816628003, 0, 0.096276275903575, 0.0130737500702787, 
    0), B_lineage_MCPcounter = c(3.22976184932414, 0.999937132744161, 
    2.44679609260375, 2.18366172005067, 3.42493856429233, 1.4932419196133
    ), NK_cells_MCPcounter = c(0.149114080210185, 1.5506238339929, 
    1.97542993865811, 1.54505176275885, 0.620011061165289, 0.84989072770901
    ), Monocytic_lineage_MCPcounter = c(0.328915862873467, 0.457286328311746, 
    0.0638034411707617, 0.368798749739538, 0.16302900722482, 
    0.398176789851353), Myeloid_dendritic_cells_MCPcounter = c(4.85126516101213, 
    11.2938901474743, 10.5667703803826, 9.88554687157974, 1.57514347934309, 
    4.48621954035491), Neutrophils_MCPcounter = c(3.40627005016468, 
    4.33560355387993, 3.49475468671847, 5.83507305193147, 4.12282956726829, 
    4.67640813832648), Endothelial_cells_MCPcounter = c(23.2898490872401, 
    34.9595179096261, 31.6235821261562, 20.4751483833849, 6.29415791571808, 
    16.3744587719839), Fibroblasts_MCPcounter = c(0.951855967142354, 
    2.48977894056088, 1.06675072800774, 1.14247071885814, 0.0462281812233341, 
    0.577850386059767), Bcells_EPIC = c(0.0187847910767288, 0.0161101438602955, 
    0.0139334537873857, 0.0154918295803112, 0.0122392669418857, 
    0.0117627949204868), CAFs_EPIC = c(0.00062681392489947, 0.000348105360310486, 
    0.000338790810638996, 0.00162805830410826, 0.000245050068480964, 
    0.000114054388822975), CD4_Tcells_EPIC = c(0.177580148743503, 
    0.20282681682959, 0.20444936422955, 0.153815760906293, 0.108266745828814, 
    0.14311556846472), CD8_Tcells_EPIC = c(0.0548016346644402, 
    0.0597454048033118, 0.0567221574573126, 0.0421348006109705, 
    0.0314239709341409, 0.0390931882436169), Endothelial_EPIC = c(0.0223517567857523, 
    0.0422157905006953, 0.0363948358655719, 0.0216334787013179, 
    0.011640345268451, 0.0212177152708688), Macrophages_EPIC = c(0.00140136888420915, 
    0.00334002101805982, 0.00588851550206864, 0.00446684947312119, 
    0.00322599250154083, 0.00804310221388932), NKcells_EPIC = c(7.19540512367667e-10, 
    6.40520648685237e-08, 3.75378672878168e-09, 1.75342812401606e-10, 
    9.59787108967855e-10, 6.93285532761032e-10), otherCells_EPIC = c(0.724453485200927, 
    0.675413653575672, 0.682272878593685, 0.760829222248535, 
    0.8329586274969, 0.77665357580431), StromalScore_estimate = c(-908.314834613568, 
    -823.569239890163, -597.457498658664, -793.908411527929, 
    -617.976644874822, -754.520965036109), ImmuneScore_estimate = c(895.77653319576, 
    805.064482983259, 846.625141170117, 886.115230243143, 957.814714973109, 
    810.670590245889), ESTIMATEScore_estimate = c(-12.5383014178079, 
    -18.5047569069039, 249.167642511454, 92.2068187152142, 339.838070098287, 
    56.1496252097799), TumorPurity_estimate = c(0.823554757300883, 
    0.824051231020115, 0.801161887852948, 0.814736283331551, 
    0.793126205600767, 0.817793777486903), B_cells_quantiseq = c(0.0343114236157267, 
    0.0247335058375006, 0.0351936194618154, 0.0243040467086089, 
    0.0235411681108391, 0.00980807899999976), Macrophages_M1_quantiseq = c(0.0427773558587626, 
    0.0994823273641993, 0.143523132723282, 0.0155152413755307, 
    0, 0.0309560983665467), Macrophages_M2_quantiseq = c(0, 0.0167639885919336, 
    0, 0.0208647907593858, 0.242472108214098, 0.0993325644666538
    ), Monocytes_quantiseq = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0.182690011795202, 
    0), Neutrophils_quantiseq = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), NK_cells_quantiseq = c(0.00975016298706783, 
    0, 0, 0.00211205831425449, 0.00316103546471194, 0.0063777806598305
    ), T_cells_CD4_quantiseq = c(0.0490776110053321, 0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0), T_cells_CD8_quantiseq = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Tregs_quantiseq = c(0.00792398534827099, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Dendritic_cells_quantiseq = c(0.153026521327566, 
    0.397498489978873, 0.355762061425052, 0.477189974279164, 
    0, 0.316218206216205), Other_quantiseq = c(0.703132939857274, 
    0.461521688227493, 0.465521186389851, 0.460013888563056, 
    0.548135676415149, 0.537307271290764)), row.names = c("H1", 
"H2", "H3", "H4", "C1", "C2"), class = "data.frame")
```

This looks something like this:

```
 B_cells_memory_CIBERSORT Plasma_cells_CIBERSORT T_cells_CD8_CIBERSORT T_cells_CD4_naive_CIBERSORT T_cells_CD4_memory_resting_CIBERSORT
H1               0.00000000            0.000000000           0.000000000                           0                           0.41371431
H2               0.00000000            0.030169327           0.000000000                           0                           0.33703829
H3               0.00000000            0.007080565           0.000000000                           0                           0.33386782
H4               0.00000000            0.004821867           0.000000000                           0                           0.31476018
C1               0.01358637            0.003618670           0.003662728                           0                           0.04683073
C2               0.00000000            0.001750569           0.012933916                           0                           0.07251181
   T_cells_CD4_memory_activated_CIBERSORT T_cells_follicular_helper_CIBERSORT T_cells_regulatory_.Tregs._CIBERSORT
H1                            0.008911437                          0.00000000                          0.000000000
H2                            0.000000000                          0.03472931                          0.012942310
H3                            0.000000000                          0.00000000                          0.000000000
H4                            0.000000000                          0.00000000                          0.000000000
C1                            0.000000000                          0.00000000                          0.023439410
C2                            0.000000000                          0.01337471                          0.006956932
   T_cells_gamma_delta_CIBERSORT NK_cells_resting_CIBERSORT NK_cells_activated_CIBERSORT Monocytes_CIBERSORT Macrophages_M0_CIBERSORT
H1                    0.00000000                 0.09435735                            0         0.001636697                        0
H2                    0.00000000                 0.02917728                            0         0.006312796                        0
H3                    0.01235769                 0.06030000                            0         0.055193205                        0
H4                    0.00000000                 0.08805013                            0         0.000000000                        0
C1                    0.00000000                 0.03110989                            0         0.000000000                        0
C2                    0.00000000                 0.04936121                            0         0.012394321                        0
   Macrophages_M1_CIBERSORT Macrophages_M2_CIBERSORT Dendritic_cells_resting_CIBERSORT Dendritic_cells_activated_CIBERSORT
H1              0.000000000              0.004269678                       0.000000000                         0.022586193
H2              0.006273756              0.000000000                       0.017964994                         0.010937999
H3              0.003422236              0.000000000                       0.011873199                         0.002978765
H4              0.017791737              0.000000000                       0.007086708                         0.000000000
C1              0.000000000              0.000000000                       0.018232184                         0.007091986
C2              0.000000000              0.000000000                       0.009821986                         0.008590266
   Mast_cells_resting_CIBERSORT Mast_cells_activated_CIBERSORT Neutrophils_CIBERSORT T_cells_MCPcounter CD8_T_cells_MCPcounter
H1                   0.00000000                     0.06603953             0.0000000         0.39702291             0.00000000
H2                   0.00000000                     0.05950133             0.0000000         0.93282357             0.05526936
H3                   0.00000000                     0.19279383             0.0000000         0.41854915             0.00000000
H4                   0.09337482                     0.02581733             0.0533343         1.10730217             0.11239431
C1                   0.79420052                     0.02670563             0.0000000         0.07116934             0.09771177
C2                   0.73145466                     0.04305862             0.0000000         0.33733228             0.00000000
   Cytotoxic_lymphocytes_MCPcounter B_lineage_MCPcounter NK_cells_MCPcounter Monocytic_lineage_MCPcounter Myeloid_dendritic_cells_MCPcounter
H1                       0.00288836            3.2297618           0.1491141                   0.32891586                           4.851265
H2                       0.09468678            0.9999371           1.5506238                   0.45728633                          11.293890
H3                       0.00000000            2.4467961           1.9754299                   0.06380344                          10.566770
H4                       0.09627628            2.1836617           1.5450518                   0.36879875                           9.885547
C1                       0.01307375            3.4249386           0.6200111                   0.16302901                           1.575143
C2                       0.00000000            1.4932419           0.8498907                   0.39817679                           4.486220
   Neutrophils_MCPcounter Endothelial_cells_MCPcounter Fibroblasts_MCPcounter Bcells_EPIC    CAFs_EPIC CD4_Tcells_EPIC CD8_Tcells_EPIC
H1               3.406270                    23.289849             0.95185597  0.01878479 0.0006268139       0.1775801      0.05480163
H2               4.335604                    34.959518             2.48977894  0.01611014 0.0003481054       0.2028268      0.05974540
H3               3.494755                    31.623582             1.06675073  0.01393345 0.0003387908       0.2044494      0.05672216
H4               5.835073                    20.475148             1.14247072  0.01549183 0.0016280583       0.1538158      0.04213480
C1               4.122830                     6.294158             0.04622818  0.01223927 0.0002450501       0.1082667      0.03142397
C2               4.676408                    16.374459             0.57785039  0.01176279 0.0001140544       0.1431156      0.03909319
   Endothelial_EPIC Macrophages_EPIC NKcells_EPIC otherCells_EPIC StromalScore_estimate ImmuneScore_estimate ESTIMATEScore_estimate
H1       0.02235176      0.001401369 7.195405e-10       0.7244535             -908.3148             895.7765              -12.53830
H2       0.04221579      0.003340021 6.405206e-08       0.6754137             -823.5692             805.0645              -18.50476
H3       0.03639484      0.005888516 3.753787e-09       0.6822729             -597.4575             846.6251              249.16764
H4       0.02163348      0.004466849 1.753428e-10       0.7608292             -793.9084             886.1152               92.20682
C1       0.01164035      0.003225993 9.597871e-10       0.8329586             -617.9766             957.8147              339.83807
C2       0.02121772      0.008043102 6.932855e-10       0.7766536             -754.5210             810.6706               56.14963
   TumorPurity_estimate B_cells_quantiseq Macrophages_M1_quantiseq Macrophages_M2_quantiseq Monocytes_quantiseq Neutrophils_quantiseq
H1            0.8235548       0.034311424               0.04277736               0.00000000             0.00000                     0
H2            0.8240512       0.024733506               0.09948233               0.01676399             0.00000                     0
H3            0.8011619       0.035193619               0.14352313               0.00000000             0.00000                     0
H4            0.8147363       0.024304047               0.01551524               0.02086479             0.00000                     0
C1            0.7931262       0.023541168               0.00000000               0.24247211             0.18269                     0
C2            0.8177938       0.009808079               0.03095610               0.09933256             0.00000                     0
   NK_cells_quantiseq T_cells_CD4_quantiseq T_cells_CD8_quantiseq Tregs_quantiseq Dendritic_cells_quantiseq Other_quantiseq
H1        0.009750163            0.04907761                     0     0.007923985                 0.1530265       0.7031329
H2        0.000000000            0.00000000                     0     0.000000000                 0.3974985       0.4615217
H3        0.000000000            0.00000000                     0     0.000000000                 0.3557621       0.4655212
H4        0.002112058            0.00000000                     0     0.000000000                 0.4771900       0.4600139
C1        0.003161035            0.00000000                     0     0.000000000                 0.0000000       0.5481357
C2        0.006377781            0.00000000                     0     0.000000000                 0.3162182       0.5373073
```

My objective is to remove the end part of the each colnames.

So I tried this:

```
names(cibersort2) <- gsub("_CIBERSORT|_MCPcounter","",names(cibersort2),fixed = TRUE)
```

The above line works for single argument such as if I give `gsub("_CIBERSORT),"",names(cibersort2),fixed = TRUE)`, it doesn't work for both `_CIBERSORT|_MCPcounter`

I'm sure the `|` is not working here but that I saw in other solution not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Any suggestion or help really appreciated.

Comment: Try removing `fixed = TRUE` in your `gsub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/grep) of `gsub`:

> fixed
> logical. If TRUE, pattern is a string to be matched as is. Overrides all conflicting arguments.

Which means when `fixed = TRUE` is specified in `gsub`, the `|` symbol would be treated as a literal string (`\\|`) in your search pattern rather than carrying the function of "or". In your case, the `gsub` will replace the exact pattern `_CIBERSORT|_MCPcounter`, which is absent in your query string.

Therefore, to `gsub` for multiple patterns, you need to drop the `fixed = TRUE` argument or set `fixed = FALSE`.

```
names(cibersort2) <- gsub("_CIBERSORT|_MCPcounter","",names(cibersort2))
```